# 1 Mean T-Test, Statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

During a flu vaccine shortage in the United States, it was believed that 45 percent of vaccine-eligible people received flu vaccine. The results of a survey given to a random sample of 2,350 vaccine-eligible people indicated that 978 of the 2,350 people had received flu vaccine. What test would determine if the belief that 45 percent of the vaccine-eligible people had received flu vaccine is accurate?

A. 1-Proportion Z-test

B. 1-Mean T-Test

C. Chi-Squared Test for Goodness of Fit

D. Chi-Squared Test for Homogeneity

E. Chi-Squared Test for Independence

*My Answer*

**B. 1 mean T Test**

*Would Appriciate Feedback*

Comment: No. Hint: ____ out of ____.

Comment: Chi-Squared Test for Homogeneity?

Comment: No. Stronger hint: a FRACTION of the population got the vaccine.

Comment: chi-square test for independence?

Comment: Okay , give me a reason why you think it's what you say.